# check an interval step by step if a specific criterion is fulfilled

Tags: matlab, loops, frequency, measurement, bigdata

first of all I am very new in programming.

I have large number of frequency measured values. I want to check if the frequency (f) has the following characteristics over the whole interval of `t = 900 %sec.`:

```
f>=50.05 || f<=49.95
```

But the program should check every second for the next 900 sec. if the criterion is fulfilled. So it should check it for `f(i:i+900)`. I tried to solve it with a loop to find those intervals, but the number of data is too large. Here is the code:

```
T1 = zeros(length_f,1);
T2 = zeros(length_f,1);
for i = 1:length_f
    if f(i:i+900)>=50.05
    T1(i)=1;
    end
    if f(i:i+900)<=49.95
    T2(i)=1;
    end
end

K1=find(T1==1);
K2=find(T2==2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: be careful! `length()` is a built-in-matlab function

Comment: ok, i will change it to `length_f`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the profiler on a smaller version of your data to check which lines lead to your issue of "the data are too large".

If I've understood correctly, you want to check the first 900 seconds of your data, and if the `i`-th value satisfy either of your conditions, check up to the `i+900`-th point, recording the indices of all points which satisfy the conditions in vectors `K1` and `K2`.

I would suggest modifying your loop to use a `while` loop and controlling your counting variables manually. Something like

```
% Fixed parameters
f_upper_lim = 50.05;
f_lower_lim = 49.95;
max_count = 900;

% Variables
% Position in f
ii = 1;
% Positions left to test
count = max_count;
% Indices where f(ii) >= f_upper_lim
K1 = [];
% Indices where f(ii) <= f_lower_lim
K2 = [];

while count > 0 & ii <= length_f
  if f(ii) >= f_upper_lim
    K1 = [K1, ii];
    % Reset count - test next max_count values
    count = max_count;
  elseif f(ii) <= f_lower_lim
    K2 = [K2, ii];
    % Reset count - test next max_count values
    count = max_count;
  else
    count = count - 1;
  end % if
  ii = ii + 1;
end % while
```

As ever, you should test this with a small set of data.